# flutter set selected buttons color dynamically

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a category bar in my flutter application. Initially all the category names were hard coded but now I'm getting the category names from `json` data.

what I need to do is to set a green container color for the selected button and the text will be white. And the other buttons will be black text + white container.

When I had hardcoded data I checked the button's index individually like this:

for container:

```
color: buttonIndex == 0 ? Color(0xff75c760) : Colors.white,
```

for button text:

```
buttonIndex == 0 ? Colors.white : Colors.black,
```

but now the as there can be any number of category name's I dont know how to turn this into a dynamic one.

Full Code:

```
class _RecipeCategoryBarState extends State<RecipeCategoryBar> {
  late AppData appData;
  int buttonIndex = 0;
  void setIndex(int val) {
    setState(() {
      buttonIndex = val;
    });
  }

  Widget recipeCategoryButton() {
    return Container();
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    appData = Store.instance.getAppData();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      height: 50.0,
      child: ListView.builder(
        scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
        itemCount: appData.recipeCategories!.length,
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
          return ButtonBar(
            children: <Widget>[
              Material(
                color: buttonIndex == 0 ? Color(0xff75c760) : Colors.white,
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
                clipBehavior: Clip.antiAlias,
                child: Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                    horizontal: 5,
                  ),
                  child: Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: [
                      TextButton(
                        onPressed: () {
                          setIndex(0);
                          widget.sendDataToParent(index);
                        },
                        child: Text(
                          appData.recipeCategories![index].categoryName!,
                          style: TextStyle(
                            color:
                                buttonIndex == 0 ? Colors.white : Colors.black,
                            fontSize: 12,
                            fontFamily: "Poppins",
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: In what format are the colors delievered?

Comment: I'm sorry, I dont get what you mean by "what format"

Comment: 6digit hex color codes would be one possible format for colors.

Comment: oh, I see. I was using `Color(0xff75c760)` this format

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand what you want to do, you can achieve it by using the `index` given by the `ListView.builder` instead of your `buttonIndex` variable.